# Duplicate zero in array by modifying the array in place

Tags: java, arrays

> *There is a fixed length array `arr` of integers, duplicate each occurrence of zero, shifting the remaining elements to the right. The elements beyond the length of the original array are not written.*

We have to modify input array in place and doesn't have to create new array.

So I created that but it is duplicating the zero which is at the end of array and not the previous zeros. Can somebody help me with this?

```java
public static void addPos() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 8 };
    int result[] = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            int loc = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < loc; j++) {
                result[j] = arr[j];
                result[loc] = 0;
            }
            for (int j = loc + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                result[j] = arr[j - 1];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
        System.out.println(result[k]);
}
```

### Output

```
1
2
0
3
0
5
0
0
7
```

```
Expected output:
1
2
0
0
3
0
0
5
0
```

Comment: It specifically says not to do `int result[]=new int[arr.length];`. Start by reading the instructions carefully.

Comment: You didn't show what is the expected output for the given example arr in your code.

Comment: I would also move the line " result[loc] = 0; " outside of it's for loop. That only needs to be done once.

Comment: Added the expected output

Comment: Thanks,Given solution is working. But if I have to edit my code then i have to write result[loc]=0 outside of all for loop means when all the for loops brackets are closed but then also same output is coming. Or is there anything I have to edit?

Answer (score 14):

Every iteration of the loop overwrites the results from the previous iteration, so the end result only shows the results from the last iteration, which duplicates the last 0 is duplicated.

One way to solve this is by iterating backwards "right to left". It simplifies a lot of things. You can get rid of the auxiliary `result` array. The basic idea is, go backwards in the array, and every time you find a 0, you duplicate it by rewriting the array to the right of the zero.

```
public static void addPos() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 8};

    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            // duplicate it!
            for (int j = arr.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
                arr[j] = arr[j-1];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        System.out.println(arr[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinon, this is a clear example of how a great Stack Overflow answer should look. It is straight to the point, begins with a few essential comments which are followed by a clean piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

The for loop keeps overwriting the values in result array, hence the result shows only last duplication.You should not be using the result array at all.Keep shipting values in the original array itself.

You can refer to below code.

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
  if(arr[i]==0){
    for(int j=arr.length-1;j>i;j--){
    arr[j]=arr[j-1];
     }
     i++;
   }
   
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't your inner for loop just fill all the elements after `i` with zero?

Comment: The line you are talking about is outside inner for loop and inside if condition

Comment: no, I'm meaning the loop. Oh, I see, it's not the zero, it's the following element that's copied to the end, e.g. https://ideone.com/bokEaZ

Answer (score 2):

```
public void duplicateZeros(int[] arr)
```

{
int i=0;

```
    while(i<arr.length)
    {
        
        if(arr[i]==0)
        {
            int j=arr.length-1;
            while(j != i)
            {
                arr[j]=arr[j-1];
                j--;
            }
            i=i+2;
        }
        else
        {
            i=i+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using any other Array.

```
class Solution {
public void duplicateZeros(int[] arr) {
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]==0){
            
            for(int j=arr.length-1;j>i;j--){
                arr[j]=arr[j-1];   
            }
            i=i+1; 
        }
         
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So one has this:

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 8 };

public static void duplicateZeros(int[] arr) {
```

and should get

```
{ 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 8 }
        v___
{ 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7 }
                 v___
{ 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5, 0 }
```

This looks like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    if (arr[i - 1] == 0) {
        insert at i a 0;
    }
}

insert at i a 0:
    // First move the remaining to the right: i .. n-2
    ...
    // Then fill in the zero
    arr[i] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Python solution for anyone interested adapted from [here](https://ao.ms/how-to-duplicate-zeros-in-place-using-python/)

the solution is non-trivial if you do not separate the action of the pointer iterating over the list and the insertions. It's very easy to write a for-loop that adds 0's ad-infinitum.

```
def duplicateZeros(arr):

    # define the incrementor
    i = 0

    # loop through all dynamic elements
    while i < len(arr)-1:
        # if the character is a zero
        if arr[i]==0:
            # remove the last item from the array
            arr.pop()
            # insert a zero in front of current element
            arr.insert(i+1, 0)
            # move one place forward
            i += 1

        # increment to the next character
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** Loop from start to end. If zero is found, move the elements from next index and fill the next as zero and skip next.

```
public static void duplicateZeros(int[] arr) {
    System.out.println("BEGIN duplicateZeros:" + Arrays.toString(arr));

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            move(arr, i);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("END duplicateZeros:" + Arrays.toString(arr) +"\n");
}

private static void move(int[] arr, int index) {
    // move to the right from index+1
    for(int i=arr.length-1; i>index; i--) {
        arr[i] = arr[i-1];
    }
    
    // fill 0 at index
    arr[index] = 0 ;
}
```

**Solution2:** Loop from end to start. If zero is found, move the elements from next index and fill the current index as zero.

```
public static void duplicateZeros(int[] arr) {
    System.out.println("BEGIN duplicateZeros:" + Arrays.toString(arr));
    
    for(int i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            move(arr, i);
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("END duplicateZeros:" + Arrays.toString(arr) +"\n");
}

private static void move(int[] arr, int index) {
    // move to the right from index+1
    for(int i=arr.length-1; i>index; i--) {
        arr[i] = arr[i-1];
    }
    
    // fill 0 at index
    arr[index] = 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def duplicateZeros(self, arr: List[int]) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify arr in-place instead.
        """
        if len(arr)==0:
            return arr
        index = 0
        while index < len(arr):
            print(index,end=" ")
            if arr[index]==0:
                arr.insert(index+1,0)
                arr.pop()
                index+=1
            index+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public void duplicateZeros(int[] arr) {
        Queue<Integer> queue=new LinkedList<Integer>();
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i]==0){
                queue.add(0);
                queue.add(0);
            }else{
                queue.add(arr[i]);
            }
            Integer first=queue.poll();
            arr[i]=first;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).